# How to print two array at the same time in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate through two associative arrays at the same time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395889/iterate-through-two-associative-arrays-at-the-same-time-in-php)

I have two arrays `$name[]` and `$type[]`. I want to print those arraya through foreach loop like this,

```
<?php
foreach($name as $v && $type as $t)
{
echo $v;
echo $t;
}
?>
```

I know this is wrong way then tell me correct way to do this.

Comment: Are both arrays always of the same length?

Comment: @deceze: I 'm sure this is a dupe of *something*, just not of that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do this like that. You need to do one of the following:

1. use a `for` loop and "share" the index variable, or
2. manually iterate with [`each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) and friends, or
3. zip the two arrays together with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

#### Example with `for`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); ++$i) {
    echo $name[$i];
    echo $type[$i];
}
```

Possible issues: The arrays need to be numerically indexed, and if they are not the same length it matters a lot which array you use `count` on. You should either target the shorter array or take appropriate measures to not index into the longer array out of bounds.

#### Example with `each`:

```
reset($name);  // most of the time this is not going to be needed,
reset($type);  // but let's be technically accurate

while ((list($k1, $n) = each($name)) && (list($k2, $t) = each($type))) {
    echo $n;
    echo $t;
}
```

Possible issues: If the arrays are not the same length then this will stop processing elements after the "shorter" array runs out. You can change that by swapping `||` for `&&`, but then you have to account for one of `$n` and `$t` not always having a meaningful value.

#### Example with `array_map`:

```
// array_map with null as the callback: read the docs, it's documented
$zipped = array_map(null, $name, $type);

foreach($zipped as $tuple) {
    // here you could do list($n, $t) = $tuple; to get pretty variable names
    echo $tuple[0]; // name
    echo $tuple[1]; // type
}
```

Possible issues: If the two arrays are not the same length then the shorter one will be extended with nulls; you have no control over this. Also, while convenient this approach does use additional time and memory.

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid': In this case it's the same. Just preference.

Comment: Ooh, option 3 is *very* pretty.

Comment: Thank you for this example. I was worried that I would have to hard code a multidimensional array (and I don't understand those so I'm kinda avoiding them for now).
I found array_map to be the most organized method for what I'm working on

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are always the same length, and if the elements are unique, and if all the values of `$name` are strings or integers, you could use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
foreach (array_combine($name, $type) as $v => $t) {
    echo $v, $t;
}
```

`array_combine` makes a new array, with the elements of the first array providing the keys, while the elements of the second array provide the values.

Comment: Nice conception, but since array keys can only be strings and integers this won't work across the board.

Comment: @Jon A very good point. You could do `serialize`, of course, but that would be Abundantly Stupid!

Comment: There's an obscure trick that does something similar with `array_map` and a `null` callback, have a look at the third option in my answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use manual array iteration functions [`next()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [`current()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) in while loop:

```
reset($a);
reset($b);

while( (next($a) !== false) || (next($b) !== false)){
    $t = current($a);
    $v = current($b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($name), count($type)); $i++) { 
    if(isset($name[$i]))
        echo 'name[' . $i . '] = ' . $name[$i];  
    if(isset($type[$i]))
        echo 'type[' . $i . '] = ' . $type[$i]; 
}
```